# Programmatically resize sidebar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) I can make a sidebar and then a user can manually resize it. Its size then persists between runs

I have a user preference that can lead to a page being shown inside the sidebar which does not fit the default width so I would to be able to set the width myself upon a change to this preference. I can listen on the change but there is no documented method to resize the bar

Thanks very much and I appreciate any help

Comment: Get the DOM id of your sidebar and do `.width = blah` should persist. Doing `.style.width` probably wont persist though.